# which of these two methods are better to manipulate state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When changing State in React which one of these would be the preferred way ( or is there no preferred way )

1)

```
handleDeleteOption(optionToRemove){

this.setState((prevState)=>({
options: prevState.options.filter((option)=>{
  return optionToRemove !== option    })
}))
}
```

or

2)

```
handleDeleteOption(option){

this.setState((prevState)=>{
  const newArray = [...prevState.options]
  newArray.splice(newArray.indexOf(option), 1) 
  return{
    options: newArray
  }
})
}
```

thank you !

Comment: Filter is considered a more "functional" approach and doesn't use methods which mutate the array so you don't need to have the knowledge that you should spread it to a new one first. It also looks cleaner and can be chained. You also don't need to worry about indexOf not finding the element and having unexpected outcomes if not checked for.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's also:

```
this.setState({
 options: [...this.state.options.splice(optionIndex, 1)]
})
```

A shorter and cleaner way.

Comment: wouldn't that be directly modifying the state in memory, which isn't recommended?

Comment: We're using spread operator! This will clone the object. So, no mutation.

Comment: suggestions: 1- splice will return the removed element, not the new array without that item, 2- setState is async so `this.state` in setState is not a good idea.

Comment: @MayankShukla I have only given an example, OP may use `const {options} = this.state` outside the setState.

Comment: thing is, for these kind of scenarios we use functional setState (prevState), also don't take it personally, it was just a suggestion :)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal when you need to calculate new state value based on some previous state value you should pass a callback function to `this.setState` method instead of directly reading from `this.state`. Otherwise the chances are to get not synced data. See more on official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate